# It is possible to send multiple post requests at once to a Node/Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a little confused to understand whether Express can handle multiple GET and POST requests at once.

Just for an example, let's suppose 500 users are active on my website, and 200 of those users make a POST request by summiting an HTML form. Will Express process all the POST requests simultaneously or one POST request at a time?

If express can not process all requests at once, what might be the solution to this?

Comment: Yes it can process the requests in the meantime, although it is single threaded but the event loop works fine.

Comment: Here's some info about this: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#run-your-app-in-a-cluster